# Linq join tables and use contains

Tags: c#, linq

I have hierarchical one to many relationship chain.

I would like to retrieve objects from the last many chain of the table depending on the selection in the first table

Here is my linq:
 var list= new List();
ObjectA is the root table

```
IEnumerable<ObjectA> selectedObjectsAs = GetGrantedObjectAs(id).ToList();

IEnumerable<ObjectC> selectedObjectsCs 
                      = from c in DbContext.ObjectCs
                      join b in DbContext.ObjectBs on c.BId equals b.Id
                      join a in DbContext.ObjectAs on b.AId equals a.Id
                      where selectedObjectsAs.Contains(a)
                      select c;

list.AddRange(selectedObjectsCs.ToList());
```

When the last line runs to AddRange I get the following exception

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'ObjectA'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Any idea where the the problem could be?

Comment: "Does not work" is not helpful. Does it fail to compile? Does it give a result you don't expect? I assure you, the query does exactly what it says it does, so it's not clear what your question is.  What's your specific question?

Comment: In the process of debugging to get actual exception. I will post it in a minute

Comment: So your process here is to ask on SO first and investigate the problem later?  I think you have this backwards.

Comment: No the only reason I ask the question is because I am not comfortable with linq and I thought someone easily could spot the issue on the expression.

Comment: Are you remoting the query to a database?

Comment: What does `GetGrantedObjectAs` do? Could you explain?

Comment: GetGrantedObjectAs gets list of allowed OjbectA. from database table.

Comment: But with the same Id? Please, try to post an example to see the logic you are trying to apply

Comment: fixed the issue by using GetGrantedObjectAs(id).Selec(x=>x.Id) and then where selectedObjectsAs.Contains(a.Id)

Comment: You're attempting to remote the entirity of an ObjectA -- whatever that is -- over to the database, and the database remoting layer does not know how to do that.

Comment: @EricLippert i am not really sure what exactly you mean by remote the entity of an ObjectA. That is simply using Repository pattern to get data from a table  the GetGrantedObjectAs(id) method simply retrieves a list of ObjectA from a table. I would be happy to understand what exactly you mean. But I fixed the issue as I described. Somehow it doesn't like the objects but using ids instead works fine. As the error actually states that Only primitive and enumration types are supported. but not list of objects.

Comment: @akd: Correct. Integers can be remoted across to the database for it to use when running the query. Your arbitrary business objects cannot.

Answer (score 0):

```
join b in DbContext.ObjectBs on c.BId equals c.Id
```

You're attempting to join `b` with two references to `c`.

Changing `c.Id`  to `b.Id` I would presume would work.

Comment: that was just a typo mistake.

Comment: Ah okay. Can you edit the question containing the error / results it gives?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for (using navigation properties):

```
//Contains method in Linq to entities only works with primitive types or enumeration types
var IdsOfA=GetGrantedObjectAs(id).Select(a=>a.Id);
var selectedObjectsCs=DbContext.ObjectAs.Where(a=>IdsOfA.Contains(a.Id))
                                        .SelectMany(a=>a.Bs.SelectMany(b=>b.Cs))
```

Comment: haven't tried this one yet but not sure which one would be better or whether this results in the same query as my solution. I need to use sql profiler to find out. The idea is that objectCs are list of roles. ObjectA is the root level. ObjectA>ObjectB>ObjectC. if user has a role in ObjectA then I need to find out what are the actual roles that specific role is mapped to by going through ObjectB then ObjectC by following the navitation properties to get user roles from ObjectC. Similar if a user is given role in ObjectB then I need to find what are the actual roles that maps the role in ObjectC